# IIs page (internet information service) always appears when I try to create virtual host web site by xampp

Tags: laravel, virtualhost

Internet Information Services on typing localhost(IIS) when I trying to create virtual host on by laravel project called **usingapi.test**

I'm using xampp and tried to change the port in **httpd.conf** and the other two files who are **httpd.vhosts.conf** like:

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/usingapi/public"
    ServerName usingapi.test

and the other one in windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts file to:

**127.0.0.1 usingapi.test**

but always shows me IIS page, i'm very tiered of thsi please help

Comment: If you've already got IIS running on port 80, XAMPP can't coexist with it on the same port. Chances are your XAMPP is complaining somewhere that the port is already in use.

Comment: I tried to change the port number also but no way, appears the same problem. Do you know another way to fix this terrible issue?

Comment: Sure, turn off IIS if you don't intend to use it.